# In Oracle, I want to use a sequence and not allow Insert on the column that uses the sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I want to make happen the same that happens when I do the following

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST1" 
(   
     "ID" NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "APPCODE" VARCHAR2(1)
);
  Table TEST1 created.
INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID, APPCODE) VALUES (1,'A');
   Error starting at line : 6 in command -
   INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID, APPCODE) VALUES (1,'A')
   Error at Command Line : 50 Column : 1
   Error report -
   SQL Error: ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
INSERT INTO TEST (APPCODE) VALUES ('A');
   1 row inserted.
```

but I want to use named sequences, created by me. I want the same behavior as
when using the "ALWAYS" keyword (as in "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY") and at the same time use my own named sequences, but I don't know how.

With named sequences, it seems to be impossible to avoid that an INSERT uses the ID COLUMN on the insert. But maybe there is a way? This is the question I'm asking. Below I create a named sequence and show the difference (I can't figure out how to prevent the ID column to be allowed on the insert).

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST2 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NOMAXVALUE;
    Sequence SEQ_TEST2 created.
INSERT INTO TEST2 (APPCODE) VALUES ('A'); /* This is ok */
   1 row inserted.
INSERT INTO TEST2 (ID,APPCODE) VALUES (1928,'A'); /* This is NOT ok */
   1 row inserted.
```

The second insert above is what I want to prevent from happening, it shouldn't be possible to insert on the ID column. I don't care how to prevent it to happen, doesn't have to be the same way that the  "ALWAYS" keyword on the TEST1 table works, but I would like to prevent it from happening. Anyone knows please how to to it?

Comment: Before 12c, [the standard way was to use a sequence + a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle/11296469#11296469). There's a lot of other examples on here if you search.

Comment: *"but I want to use sequences"* - why do you want to use sequences?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson sequences appear as separate objects, can be created and dropped, and don't give differences between databases on sqldeveloper. At the moment I have dozens of bogus differences between tables that are exactly the same on sqldeveloper, because the ID columns use internal system sequences which are differently named. It is a problem on sqldeveloper diff yes, but I wanted to solve it with this workaround. Database diff is very important to my work

Comment: _" but I wanted to solve it with this workaround. Database diff is very important to my work"_   It would appear that your preferred "work around" is simply not available.  So then what?  How about changing your work around to something - even a manual procedure - to deal with the fact that a 'diff' will report differences that really have no consequence.

Comment: @LuisMatos thanks for the explanation. So the issue is with the generated sequence name. Unfortunately there is no supported way to specify a custom name (you could probably manually update the dictionary entry, but that could have unexpected consequences so better not). You can specify any other attribute  of the generated sequence (start with, increment by, cache etc). Perhaps this is a SQL Developer question though - maybe it has some option to ignore the name in schema diff reports? (I don't use it much so wouldn't know.)

Comment: @EdStevens sure I can write programs to read and eliminate differences that have no consequence, I just wanted to know if there was a way to avoid inserting an ID column when using a named sequence. If there isn't, then I'll have to deal with it ofc.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson unfortunately sqldeveloper has many issues, the diff tool has many small and annoying bugs and it makes it really hard for us who work with diffs between databases all the time. It does ignore the name on indexes for example but not on sequences - even if the sequences are defined exactly the same, are used in the same table and in the same column it still reports the column as a different one. Guess I'll just have to live with it

Answer (score 1):

Why do you thing that while using `IDENTITY` you do not use a `SEQUENCE`?

Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__CJAECCFH) or the example below

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST1" 
(   
     "ID" NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "APPCODE" VARCHAR2(1)
);
```

For this table Oracle creates a `sequence` for you under the over:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
insert into TEST1 (APPCODE) values ('x');
---    
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL')); 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |              |     1 |   100 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | TEST1        |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SEQUENCE               | ISEQ$$_75209 |       |       |            |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or check the dictionary

```
select SEQUENCE_NAME from USER_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS
where table_name = 'TEST1';

SEQUENCE_NAME                                                                                                                   
---------------
ISEQ$$_75209
```

In `identity_options` you can define the sequence options.

By selection `ALWAYS` or `BY DEAFULT [ON NULL]` you can adjust what is posible / now allowed to use in insert (I'm not sure from you description what is your aim).

Comment: Hi Jan. I know it creates sequences, but somehow the "always" keyword makes it impossible to insert using the "ID" column. I want to be able to do the same but using my own named sequence.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a column as a identity column, Oracle automatically creates a sequence, you just don't get to choose the name. You can view the name of the sequence that was created and will be used to populate the identity in the `DATA_DEFAULT` column of the `ALL_TAB_COLS` table.

```sql
SELECT owner,
       table_name,
       column_name,
       data_default
  FROM all_tab_cols
 WHERE identity_column = 'YES';
```

You can query the next value `.nextval` (and after that the current) value `.currval` of the sequence, but you can't reset or change its value directly (`alter sequence ...`), instead you'd need to change the table column, see [oracle how to change the next autogenerated value of the identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32574084/265954).

Comment: Hi EJ. My wish is to emulate the behavior of the ALWAYS keyword when I create a sequence by hand. I didn't find how to do it. It seems that it is only available when we create the identity using the keyword ALWAYS.